# PHP Fatal PHP Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

So, I am working on a project and I am having an issue as I keep getting both errors and warnings. I am quite new to PHP so be gentle. The program runs fine using PHP 5.5 However when I run the program in PHP 5.6 I receive several errors as follows;

> [10-Oct-2016 10:04:46 America/Denver] PHP Warning: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'MMR\Bundle\CodeTyperBundle\Entity\User' in /hermes/bosnaweb14a/b1234/.../application/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php on line 833
>   [10-Oct-2016 10:04:46 America/Denver] PHP Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 49 of 50 bytes in /hermes/bosnaweb14a/b1234/.../application/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php on line 833
>   [10-Oct-2016 10:04:46 America/Denver] PHP Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object in /hermes/bosnaweb14a/b1234/.../application/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php on line 837

Project Info

Platform: Symfony
PHP Version: 5.6

Affected Code

```
public function newInstance()
{
    if ($this->_prototype === null) {
        if (PHP_VERSION_ID === 50429 || PHP_VERSION_ID === 50513) {
            $this->_prototype = $this->reflClass->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
        } else {
           $this->_prototype = unserialize(sprintf('O:%d:"%s":0:{}', strlen($this->name), $this->name)); //Line 833
        }
    }

  return clone $this->_prototype; //Line 837
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do also  test for `is_object($this->_prototype)`, after the `if` or  as second condition.

Comment: And your `unserialize` faild `PHP Notice: unserialize(): ` may thats the problem

Comment: There's obviously a string in `$this->name` with unescaped characters so the `unserialize()` function isn't able to decode it.

Comment: Are the standards for unserialize different between the php versions? As it runs fine using version 5.5 but fails in version  5.6

Answer (score 1):

I tested:

`var_dump(clone $t=unserialize(sprintf('O:%d:"%s":0:{}', strlen('name'), 'name')));`

And it works.

You have to check the value of `$this->name` maybe its empty or has illegal chars.

Where is `$this->name` set in the first place?

Comment: Thanks...I will look into this

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix:
just add one more version i.e: PHP 5.6 for your if condition and it will be `PHP_VERSION_ID === 50640` in your if condition

like:

> ```
>     if ($this->_prototype === null) {
>         if (PHP_VERSION_ID === 50429 || PHP_VERSION_ID === 50513 || PHP_VERSION_ID === 50640) {
>             $this->_prototype = $this->reflClass>newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
>         } else {
>             $this->_prototype = unserialize(sprintf('O:%d:"%s":0:{}', strlen($this->name), $this->name));
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: This answer is a bit old, but I hope this does help someone in the future; the last two digits of the PHP version ID can change quickly; I am currently running 80121 on my local machine, but my docker environment is running 80120. It would be better to check on something like `PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && PHP_VERSION_ID < 50700` for PHP 5.6, for instance. Even better, use the built-in [version_compare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) function!